# Get all entries from a database matching a query with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

OK, so I have a simple blog system that I am setting up. Here is how it works:

## Writing posts

1. When the user wants to write a post, they visit a page.
 2. When they click submit, It adds it to a database with their username (grabbed from cookies with `$_SESSION['username']`)

---

## Reading Posts

1. The user navigates to the page: veiw.php?username=whatever
2. The script connects the the database and grabs all posts that match `whatever`
3. Gets the timestamp, and the post, and displays it with &nbsp between each post. 
   EG;

1/2/2018:

blablablablablablablablablablablablablablabla

---

4/6/2018
bdcpprbirv2brviov2ugtiog2rfip2rgui23rgu3riph2eirvph2v

---

I have a relatively good idea as to how to do the submit page, but I'm having trouble doing the view page. Here is my attempt (config.php included)

Veiw.php

```
<?php require('includes/config.php');

//SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE username LIKE '$query'
$username = intval($_GET['username']);
$results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE username=$username");    
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))     
{       
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $date; //Outputs: 2
$post = $row['post'];
    echo $post; //Outputs: 2
}
?>
```

Config.php

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

//set timezone
date_default_timezone_set('America/New-York');

//database credentials
define('DBHOST','REDACTED');
define('DBUSER','REDACTED');
define('DBPASS','REDACTED');
define('DBNAME','REDACTED');

//application address
define('DIR','http://REDACTED/');
define('SITEEMAIL','REDACTED');

try {

    //create PDO connection
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=".DBHOST.";charset=utf8mb4;dbname=".DBNAME, DBUSER, DBPASS);
    //$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);//Suggested to uncomment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);//Suggested to comment on production websites
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    //show error
    echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
    exit;
}

//include the user class, pass in the database connection
include('classes/user.php');
include('classes/phpmailer/mail.php');
$user = new User($db);
?>
```

I know config.php works, but testing it with my user in the URL such as https://www.code-u.org/thecollective/veiw.php?username=REDACTED returns

```
Warning: mysql_query(): No such file or directory in REDACTED/veiw.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in REDACTED/veiw.php on line 5

Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in REDACTED/veiw.php on line 6
```

---

Updated query:

```
$username = intval($_GET['username']);
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE `username` = '"$username"'");
$results->bindValue('username', intval($_GET['username']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results->execute();

while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    echo  nl2br ("\n");
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $date;
    echo  nl2br ("\n");
    $post = $row['post'];
    echo $post;
    echo nl2br ("\n ________________________________________________________________________");
}
```

It returns the page, but no results.

Comment: your mixing pdo with mysql_* stick with one, preferably the former

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `config.php` you set up a database connection using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) but then in your `view.php` you use a plain [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) for your query (which does not have access to the database details you provided to your PDO object).

(Side note: `mysql_query` is deprecated - removed in PHP 7 - so you should not be using it anyway if you are learning PHP now.)

Here's what your query would look like using the PDO object you created:

```
$results = $db->prepare('
    SELECT *
    FROM blogs
    WHERE username = :username
');
$results->bindValue('username', intval($_GET['username']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results->execute();

while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $date;
    $post = $row['post'];
    echo $post;
}
```

Using PDO over mysql_* queries is beneficial because (for one) they support prepared statements (as demonstrated above with the bindValue function), which means your queries will be protected from [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) even when using direct user input (as you might be doing here).

Comment: It gives me this now: 
Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in /home/codeu/code-u.org/thecollective/veiw.php on line 3

Comment: @DANIELMESKIN is the error on the first line (prepare)? I used a different variable name in my initial answer instead of `$db`, make sure you refer to the PDO object you create in your `config.php` by the correct name, and that `config.php` is included where you want to use it.

Comment: Actually, I have a problem. It's returning all posts now, not only the ones that match the username.

Comment: @DANIELMESKIN can you post your current query?

Comment: $username = intval($_GET['username']);
$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE `username` = '"$username"'");
$results->bindValue('username', intval($_GET['username']), PDO::PARAM_INT);
$results->execute();

while ($row = $results->fetch()) {
    echo  nl2br ("\n");
    $date = $row['date'];
    echo $date;
    echo  nl2br ("\n");
    $post = $row['post'];
    echo $post;
    echo nl2br ("\n ________________________________________________________________________");
}

Comment: @DANIELMESKIN Don't insert the username variable directly in the query, this is what the parameter binding (bindValue function) is for (and how SQL injection can be prevented). Use a parameter in the query as I did in the answer (`:username`).

Comment: I changed it to `$results = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM `blogs` WHERE `username` = ':username'");`, and It's still not returning results

Comment: @DANIELMESKIN Try without the apostrophes as well. They are not needed around the parameter and there is only one after blogs.

Comment: After removing the apostrophes, It's back to returning all of the entries